# Kinguin price request excel vba loop

Tags: vba, excel

For a hobby I'm trying to learn VBA.
For now I'm trying to get the price of a game title in an excel sheet.
I currently only have the name and ID. (https://www.kinguin.net/nl/category/{{ID}})

I managed to get it working for 1 field like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row = Range("Spel_ID").Row And _
    Target.Column = Range("Spel_ID").Column Then
        Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
        IE.Visible = False
        IE.navigate "https://www.kinguin.net/product/" & Range("Spel_ID").Value
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
        Set Doc = IE.document
        Dim sDD As String
        sDD = Doc.getElementsByClassName("relative-price-container")(0).innerText
        IE.Quit
        Dim aDD As Variant
        aDD = Split(sDD, ",")
        Range("Prijs").Value = aDD(0)
    End If
End Sub
```

However this only updates 1 field. How would I go about looping this, and filling an entire column?

**EDIT**

I managed to make a For Loop, but I'm not quite there. I'm not sure how to insert the results in a column.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("A3:A10")

For Each row In rng.Rows
  For Each cell In row.Cells
    If Target.row = Range("Spel_ID").row And _
    Target.Column = Range("Spel_ID").Column Then
        Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
        IE.Visible = True
        IE.navigate "https://www.kinguin.net/category/" & ActiveCell.Value
        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
        Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
        Set Doc = IE.document
        Dim sDD As String
        sDD = Doc.getElementsByClassName("relative-price-container")(0).innerText
        IE.Quit
        Dim aDD As Variant
        aDD = Split(sDD, ",")
        Range("Prijs").Value = aDD(0)

    End If
  Next cell
Next row


End Sub
```

(I feel like the looping range can be improved as well..)

Comment: You want to look into a For Loop. For row = 1 to lastrow. do something. Next row. There are plenty of questions regarding this subject so google, or SO search function, would be your best friend here.

Comment: I wouldn't know where to begin, I tried implementing some examples but I simply don't know how to continue since I just started with VBA, lol. Could you make an for loop example?